# How to prevent users from checking not existing urls, how to hide routes in Laravel 8.*

Tags: php, laravel

**First question was solved with findOrFail method**

Is there any way to prevent users from checking non-existing routes?

**Example**
I've got route to http://127.0.0.1:8000/event/9

but event with id 8 does not exist, if user would go to that id there is a massage:

```
Attempt to read property "photo_patch" on null (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\Laravel1\resources\views\frontend\eventView.blade.php)
```

Or any other error from db that record does not exist.

Second question
How to turn on preety URLs in laravel
So my page with display http://127.0.0.1:8000 not http://127.0.0.1:8000/events something...

I know that its somewere in config files but I cant find it.

Example class and route that uses it:

```
-----------------------------Class----------------
public function eventView($id)
    {
        $notDisplay = Auth::user();
        $eventView = Event::findOrFail($id);
        if(!$notDisplay){
            $eventView->displayed = $eventView->displayed +1;
            $eventView->save();
        }

        return view('frontend/eventView', ['eventView' => $eventView]);
    }
----------------Route-----------------
Route::get('event/' . '{id}', [App\Http\Controllers\FrontendController::class, 'eventView'])->name('eventView');
```

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Usually, such messages should be hidden in a production environment

Comment: For event you can use Event::findOrFail($event_id); It will throw 404 for non existing events.

Comment: To be honest I made whole validation so not allowed user cant for example edit someone else event or club, it goes with 403 error. So I believe my app is a bit save from unauthorized use.

With preety Urls, I just read documentation but didnt find anything usefull with it, Youtube videos are only saying about SEO friendly urls so yeah, got preety nothing with it

Comment: We need to see some code, routes, controller etc.

Comment: @MuhammadUmair that's what I was missing, thank you so much

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? The given code uses `findOrFail` already, so what does `$eventView` contain in case of a missing model?

Answer (score 1):

**First off, use the container!**
Laravel's service container is very powerful and your controller resolve use-case is one of the most common places you should be using it.  The url argument and controller argument MUST match for this to work.

Your route:

```php
Route::get('event/' . '{event}', [App\Http\Controllers\FrontendController::class, 'eventView'])->name('eventView');
```

Your Controller:

```php
public function eventView(Event $event)
    {
        return view('frontend/eventView', ['event' => $event]);
    }
```

When leveraging Laravel's dependency injection and container, you get your findOrFail() for free.  You should also remove your auth check, and handle that with route middleware.

In terms of "prettifying" urls, Laravel's route model binding feature allows you to control what property of a model is used to for container resolution.  For example, let's imagine your event has a unique slug you'd like to use instead of the auto-increment id:

```php
Route::get('event/' . '{event:slug}', [App\Http\Controllers\FrontendController::class, 'eventView'])->name('eventView');
```

Laravel's routing functionality offers a fallback feature that would allow you to fine-tune where the user is redirected if the route model binding failed.

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#fallback-routes

With regard to preventing an unauthorized individual from editing someone else's event.  The first place I would put protections in place would be at the time of persistence (when saving to the database).  While you can do this in every place in your codebase where persistence occurs, Laravel's Observer feature could be a great fit.  That way, you can be confident that no matter what code is added to your app, the ownership check will always be run before making any changes to events.

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#observers

The second place that I would put protections in place would be with a route middleware on any routes that can mutate the event.  That way, you can redirect the user away from an event they don't own before they even have a chance to attempt to edit it.

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/middleware#assigning-middleware-to-routes

Comment: "When leveraging Laravel's dependency injection and container, you get your findOrFail() for free. You should also remove your auth check, and handle that with route middleware." ---- I'm using route middleware Sir, but then it worked only between authorized and non-autorized users, so in example that user 1 would like to update user 2 data it was possible. Thank you for your tips.

Comment: In this case you have a few options.  The most common that I reach for is to use Spatie's Laravel Permissions package.  This package gives you ultra fine-grained role and permission controls that you can wrap your routes with.

https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-permission/v4/introduction

If you don't want to use a package, perhaps consider running the ownership check right inside your custom middleware, or use a Policy

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authorization#policy-methods

Comment: As far as I know, Policy method got excactly the same structure as my class code right now. Since I made it all working, I will use it in future and pass for now. Thank you tho.